# if i can mount an iso will it also install?

Tags: system-installation

Is it possible to mount an ISO with ACETONEISO and from there actually install to my HDD?
Here is what I have done. Installed ubuntu 10.10 so that I have a system. ISO does not fit a cd (which will boot) and will not boot a dvd. I have tried the ISO on usb stick, but the computer says nope. 
I can install acetoneISO from software center.

Comment: 10.10 has been end of life for some time; you should not use it.  And if you already have it installed, then what are you trying to install?

Comment: Sorry psusi, I am off-topic, as usual. Good bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AcetoneISO's features are pretty clearly [outlined](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acetoneiso/) at SourceForge, and it doesn't look like it will be able to help you in this case.

Once an OS shuts down, all mounted media should be unmounted. It isn't really possible to simply mount the image and then magically be able to install Ubuntu, you need to copy the image and install the boot loader to a USB disk or DVD or follow one of the options [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD).